# Visual studio unit test for different implementation of interface

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

I need do unit testing for two implementation classes of one particular interface. The unit test class is generic covered all the necessary test for the interface. I want to instantiate the implementation class in test unit class TestInitialize method.

Is there any way I could force the test class run twice with different implementation class instance.

```
[TestClass]
public class MyFixture
{
    [TestInitialize()]
    public void MyTestInitialize()
    {
        ITest mockInstance = new TestImplement1();
        //ITest mockInstance = new TestImplement2();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Test1 ()
    {
        mockInstance.Func1();
        ...  
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Test2 ()
    {
        ...  
    }

    ...other unit tests

 }
```

Comment: Having to test something like this indicates that there's a problem with your design. The code under test shouldn't care about which specific implementer of the interface is actually present; if that's the case, your interface is in violation of LSP.

Comment: Or it indicates that he wants a convenient way to test multiple implementations of an interface.

Answer (score 9):

For this pattern, typically you would have a base test class with the test methods, and then you would subclass it and fill in the setup method.  So it would become something like this: (I use NUnit, so I apologize if the test framework methods are a little off)

```
// don't mark this one as TestClass!
public abstract class MyBaseFixture
{
    protected ITest mockInstance;

    [TestMethod]
    public void Test1 ()
    {
        Assert(this.mockInstance.Func1() == 0);
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class MyConcreteFixture : MyBaseFixture
{
    [TestInitialize]
    public void Setup()
    {
        this.mockInstance = new ConcreteInstance1();
    }
}    

[TestClass]
public class MyOtherConcreteFixture : MyBaseFixture
{
    [TestInitialize]
    public void Setup()
    {
        this.mockInstance = new ConcreteInstance2();
    }
}
```

Comment: As an aside, if "mockInstance" is the subject of the test, please do not call "mock" as "mock" has a set meaning in unit testing.

Comment: Minor problem with Visual Studio:
"TestMethodAttribute can be defined only inside a class marked with the TestClass attribute."

Comment: Does what @anyoneis is saying mean that this isn't possible in Visual Studio?

Comment: No, just that you have to mark the abstract class as a [TestClass]. Otherwise, this works just fine!

Answer (score 3):

You should check out Greg Young's interface invariant NUnit plugin:  https://github.com/gregoryyoung/grensesnitt